# javascript array item undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why I can print out `console.log(imgs)` but I can not print out `console.log(imgs[0])`

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = [];
    var dir = "images/";
    var fileextension = ".png";

    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                imgs.push(dir+filename);
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(imgs);//ok
    console.log(imgs[0]);//undefined
    //$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ');'});
});
```

Comment: I've included jQuery

Comment: What is the ajax `data` result?

Comment: Clarify: console.log(imgs[0]) shows what? Undefined?  if so this is running before your ASYNC imgs.push() is done. Put the console.log(imgs[0])  after imgs.push() so it fires after that step is done

Comment: I console.log it, that is the entire contents of the page.

Comment: It's `undefined` because the array is empty, so there is no first element...?

Comment: I put console.log outside "success: function (data)"

Comment: i console.log(imgs) have 3 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `$.ajax` run asynchronously. 
If you add more console logs like in this example:

```
$(function() {
var imgs = [];
var dir = "images/";
var fileextension = ".png";
console.log('telling jquery to load some data')
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('data loaded');
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
            imgs.push(dir+filename);
        });
        console.log('data parsed');
    }
});

console.log("try to print images", imgs[0]);
//$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ');'});
});
```

You will see that when you tries to print `imgs[0]` ajax not yet loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The `ajax` method is async, so you need to use a callback function to use the `imgs` variable after the ajax call. Or you can move your code inside the `success function`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = [];
    var dir = "images/";
    var fileextension = ".png";
    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                imgs.push(dir+filename);
            });

            console.log(imgs);//ok
            console.log(imgs[0]);//undefined
            //$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ');'});
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Ajax is asynchronous and JavaScript is synchronous.

You need to console.log in the success callback function.